# psql procedure function can't recognize column

Tags: sql, database, psql

I have a table "b2s"

```
 Column   |         Type          | Modifiers 
 -----------+-----------------------+-----------
id        | character varying(50) | not null
list      | character varying     | not null
issue     | date                  | not null
due       | date                  |
```

1.I want to make the due column automatically 30 days more than the issue column whenever we make a new row

> Triggers:

```
b2sinsert 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON b2s 
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE dueupdate()
```

Here is the procedure:

```
BEGIN NEW.due = (issue + INTERVAL '30 days'); NEW.issue = issue; NEW.list = list; NEW.id = id; RETURN NEW; END;
```

When I attempt to insert an element in the table,  I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "issue" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (issue + INTERVAL '30 days')
            ^
QUERY:  SELECT (issue + INTERVAL '30 days')
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function dueupdate() line 1 at assignment
```

Comment: Well, if the first provided "table" is books2students, I don't  see such a column there - so why do you attempt to put a value there? also - terrible tagging. how can you tag the question as psql and mysql at the same time?!

Comment: I've attempted to make the TRIGGER occur **AFTER** INSERT OR UPDATE to arrive at the same result

Answer (score 1):

Well - if you are in the trigger - you must always address columns (of the table that riggered the trigger) prefixing them with either `NEW.` or `OLD.` tuple type (case does not matter)
Also - you dont't have to change all values. For your purpose this shoul be enough:

```
BEGIN NEW.due = (NEW.issue + INTERVAL '30 days'); END;
```

Note that affecting the NEW tuple only works in BEFORE UPDATE triggers!